# Search docker images by sha256

Tags: docker

Is that possible to search docker images by `sha256`?

Suppose that `nginx:latest` and `nginx:stable-alpine-perl` are the same image (I mean if I pull `nginx:latest`, it has `perl` inside too (let us suppose) with the following output:

```
root@saeed:/# docker pull nginx:stable-alpine-perl
stable-alpine-perl: Pulling from library/nginx
8663204ce13b: Pull complete
d953079a3046: Pull complete
ea6555c01322: Pull complete
cbc136171839: Pull complete
d0f7b76a6d37: Pull complete
8f7ff84fa6b0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a20f8020221340e9fa8f83b4d8e611b04d34731b36dfa8528c5bc45066d3ecce
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:stable-alpine-perl
docker.io/library/nginx:stable-alpine-perl
root@saeed:/# docker images --digests | grep nginx | grep a20f8020221340e9fa8f83b4d8e611b04d34731b36dfa8528c5bc45066d3ecce
nginx                                 stable-alpine-perl   sha256:a20f8020221340e9fa8f83b4d8e611b04d34731b36dfa8528c5bc45066d3ecce   40b7e6d681dd   3 weeks ago     57.8MB
```

The current version is `1.20.2`.

Suppose around two months later I want to check what image I did exactly pull.

The only information I have is `sha256:a20f8020221340e9fa8f83b4d8e611b04d34731b36dfa8528c5bc45066d3ecce`, but two months later's `nginx:latest`'s `sha256` is different.

Is there a way to search and find images by `sha256`?

I searched but found nothing unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "search"? You can specify a hash and get e.g. the tags assigned to that image just like you can with the image's name.

Comment: Possible duplncate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56646899/how-to-find-all-image-tags-of-a-running-docker-container

Comment: @tripleee suppose I have an image with `sha256:256chars` tagged as `nothing:unknow`. I want to search `sha256:256chars` in docker hub to see if it's an image there.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, but the link you provided is to search via `docker images` in local server, but I want to search in docker hub server.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, @tripleee. This is a common case in pinning project's dependencies to make sure that you either download same binaries you had downloaded years ago, or get a proper error that such binaries no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at dockerhub documentation there seems to be an endpoint dedicated for this operation called "Get Image tags".

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/#tag/images/operation/GetNamespacesRepositoriesImagesTags

General gist is that provided you know the namespace, repository, and sha256 digest of an image, you can extract all the tags that are assigned to that particular image. Sadly, the endpoint is behind docker hub's authentication requirement.

In case you're running your own registry, the following answer should be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68473409/6523288

Comment: I will need to write a program that will invoke this API, right? Is there a quick no programming solution? Note: if I need to wade through 3 or more levels of the documentation in order to gather all the knowledge required to correctly assemble a request in Postman, that is still considered programming.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski Yep. That's what you need to do.